# Graphing parabolas

Tags: functions

Parabolas $y=3x^2$ and $y=−3x^2+k$ intersect at points $M$ and $N$ that are in the first and the second quadrants respectively. Find $k$ if length of the segment $MN$ is 6.

Im really stuck on this one. Could someone please solve it listing the steps so i can learn from it? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried drawing a picture?

Comment: i dont know how to

Answer (score 1):

Both of those parabolas are symmetric about the $y$-axis. So if the length of $MN$ is $6$, that tells us the points of intersection must be at $x = \pm3$. Plugging this into the first parabola (without $k$), we can get the exact $y$-value at which these points of intersection occur. Then since we have the coordinates of $M$ and $N$, we can plug one of these points into $y = -3x^2 +k$ and solve for $k$.

Comment: i solved it and got this is k=54 correct ?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Set the equations equal to one another.

$$3x^2=-3x^2+k$$

$$6x^2=k$$

$$x^2=\frac{k}{6}$$

$$x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{k}{6}}$$

Since parabolas are vertically symmetric graphs, we have the following:

$$\sqrt{\frac{k}{6}}-6=-\sqrt{\frac{k}{6}}$$

$$2\sqrt{\frac{k}{6}}=6$$

$$\sqrt{\frac{k}{6}}=3$$

$$\frac{k}{6}=9$$

$$k=54$$